# When I ask for signup request, an error message is displayed

Tags: node.js

An error occurred when requesting signup request.

The router's req.body also prints correctly

I think an error occurred when creating

back/routes/user.js

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("req.body : " , req.body);

        // confirm membership request
        // req.body : { userId: 'tere2', password: '1234', nickname: 'te2' }

        const exUser = await db.User.findOne({
            where: {
                userId: req.body.userId,
            }   
        });
        if (exUser) {
            return res.status(403).send('ID in use')
        }
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,12);
        const newUser = await db.User.create({
            nickname:req.body.nickname,
            userId:req.body.userId,
            password:hashedPassword,
        });
        console.log(newUser);
        return res.status(200).json(newUser);
    } catch(e){

    }
});
```

error message is printed by console

Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:81)

POST http://localhost:3065/api/user net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

[image]

thanks for let me know what is reason or how to fix

thank you for reading

==============================================

error is resolved

There was an error because I didn't import db, bcrypt

Because I didn't check the error correctly.

Thank you for the answers

Comment: perhaps you have an unhandled error, your catch block doesn't return any status or response. have you tested what the console is showing in your console.logs? is it only for a new user, does existing user work?

Comment: I checked all the console messages.

I think I get an error when creating on server

Is the db setting wrong?

Comment: you right  I missed the error check. thanks

Comment: Can you please update your comments inside the code and change them into English?

Comment: ok~! thanks for advice~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following code

```
 router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
  const exUser = await db.User.findOne({userId: req.body.userId});
  if (exUser) 
  {
    return res.status(403).json({result:'이미 사용중인 아이디'});
  }

 } 
 catch(e)
 {

 }
 });
```